# Reading text file in Xquery

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xquery, osb

I'm converting "&" into `&amp;` but it cannot convert. Please give me a solution.
I'm reading a text file in this way:

```
let $docData := doc(concat($directory, '/', $filename))
return 
<my_value>{let $data := replace($docData/text(), "&amp;" , "-")
return $data
}</my_value>
```

Error message:

```
Error executing the XQuery transformation: Error parsing XML: {err}FODC0002 [{bea-err}FODC0002b]: Error parsing input XML "file://folder/test":
Error at line:1 col:14 Line:1 ';' expected, got char[32]
```

Comment: text file contains & sign

Answer (score 2):

You cannot load a text file with `doc`, it only loads xml files.

In XQuery 3.0 you can use `unparsed-text`. And you do not need concat there:

```
let $data := unparsed-text($directory || '/' || $filename)
return <my_value>{$data}</my_value>
```

Comment: when i tried it i got
An error occurred updating the resource:
line 9, column 55: {err}XP0003: Invalid expression: unexpected token:

Comment: & i'm doing this in OSB(Oracle Service Bus) & it is not working

Comment: You can see unparsed-text() in action here: http://try.zorba.io/queries/xquery/XZTZOLuKziGhY9ZvLz2HTc3HCGs%3D

Comment: OSB 11g does not support XQuery 3.0.  The string concatenation expression ("||") and fn:unparsed-text were added in 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

It's telling you that there's a problem in your XML input document, and that it saw a space (ASCII 32) where it expected a ';' character. You haven't shown us the input, but  I'm betting you wrote `&amp` where you meant to write `&amp;`